# Cache values - Spark

Tags: apache-spark, caching, databricks

Isn't intermediate variables cached automatically?

Like:

df = spark.read.csv('file.csv') ## df is not cached

df_two = df.select('column1')   ## df_two is cached automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark is lazily evaluated they will only be cached if there is an action performed on that dataset.  You can explicitly cache a value by specifiying dataset.cache() or dataset.persist().  The advantage of explicitly specifying it is you can control how its cached whether that be in DISK_ONLY/MEMORY_ONLY or a combination of MEMORY_AND_DISK.

https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-caching.html

df and df_two are not cached based on the code you provided.  They only get cached when an action is performed on them so if you did df_two.collect(), it will cache df and df_two and serialize the results back to the driver only when df_two.collect() is called.